# Using Symfony\Console for an interactive php cli application

Tags: php, symfony, console, command-line-interface, symfony-components

I want to develop an interactive command based php application, so I did some research and bumped into the Symfony\Console component. This is great, because it lets met run

```
php script.php command --option
```

However, the script then runs the command and closes, and I want to be able to run another command. So basically, something like

```
php script.php
```

Which then listens on php://stdin for commands, structured as

```
command --option
```

then runs the command and starts listening for new commands. When a specific "exit" command is run, the script should terminate.

I'm relatively new to Symfony and the Console component, so any thoughts on how to implement this, using Symfony\Console? Because I really like the way how Symfony\Console abstracts all the command-stuff away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to enclose your script.php in a cycle like that:

```
while true {
   <reading stdin>
   <executing command via Symfony2 component>
}
```

You will be able to terminate the cycle by pressing Ctrl-C

Comment: That sounds logical. However, is it possible to do something like `Command::parse($rawInput)`? I can't find something like that at first sight...

Comment: Allright, thanks I found something, however I had to search for a while. I have to use: `$app->run(new StringInput('command --option'));` and then wrap it within a `while(true)`